# naukri registration page using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

While I am automating **Naukri** registration, given an alert box, if that specific mail id is already registered.

Can anyone help me how to handle that?

```
driver.get("https://login.naukri.com/nLogin/Login.php"); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Become a member")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("z12@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456789");

Thread.sleep(50000);

Alert alert= driver.switchTo().alert();
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog that appears on naukri site is not a real alert, so you cannot switch to it or dismiss it. It's rather a div which you can close by click on X button with xpath:

```
//div[@id="forGotPassword"]//a[@title="Close"]
```

So instead of last 2 lines, you should do something like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='forGotPassword']//a[@title='Close']")).click()
```

Comment: thank you ... :) so how we can identify a pop-up alert windos

Comment: a real popup alert window is something like javascript `alert` function: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_output_alert (i.e. it's a modal popup o top of the browser). Everything else is done on HTML level, and is technically just a dynamic part of the page (usually a `div` that is either created when it's needed, or always present on the page, but hidden, but shows up when needed). So you treat it just like any other element on the page.